# Mapping class to instance

Tags: c++, static, dictionary

I'm trying to build a simple entity/component system in c++ base on the second answer to this question : [Best way to organize entities in a game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764824/best-way-to-organize-entities-in-a-game)

Now, I would like to have a static std::map that returns (and even automatically create, if possible).

What I am thinking is something along the lines of:

```
PositionComponent *pos = systems[PositionComponent].instances[myEntityID];
```

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: I agree, but let's pretend it's not static. Is there a way to map classes to instances?

Comment: PositionComponent is a position vector?

Comment: What should `systems` be exactly? Do you want to search for all entities which are exactly at this position? Or close to this position? How close? And you wonder how to organise your `systems` best to do this efficiently?

Comment: @Albert: systems is a collection of System instances, which map Components to entities. I'm trying to enable components to query other systems.

Comment: Just curious: What do you need this map for? Normally, you should not have to differ between different `Component` instances. You can use virtual functions if some specific functionality should differ.

Comment: @Albert: because some components will want to retrieve other components, so a way to get them without passing them in the constructor would prove really handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
std::map< std::type_info*, Something > systems;
```

Then you can do:

```
Something sth = systems[ &typeid(PositionComponent) ];
```

Just out of curiosity, I checked the assembler code of this C++ code

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdio>

class Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", &typeid(Foo));
}
```

to be sure that it is really a constant. Assembler (stripped) outputted by GCC (without any optimisations):

```
.globl _main
_main:
LFB27:
        pushl   %ebp
LCFI0:
        movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI1:
        pushl   %ebx
LCFI2:
        subl    $20, %esp
LCFI3:
        call    L3
"L00000000001$pb":
L3:
        popl    %ebx
        leal    L__ZTI3Foo$non_lazy_ptr-"L00000000001$pb"(%ebx), %eax
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        leal    LC0-"L00000000001$pb"(%ebx), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        addl    $20, %esp
        popl    %ebx
        leave
        ret
```

So it actually has to read the `L__ZTI3Foo$non_lazy_ptr` symbol (I wonder though that this is not constant -- maybe with other compiler options or with other compilers, it is). So a constant may be slightly faster (if the compiler sees the constant at compile time) because you save a read.

Comment: Well, I never have seen any usecase where I needed to map classes to something. :) But in case you want to do that, I think there is nothing wrong with this solution. Or is there? This should be perfectly valid C++. And it is also efficient.

Comment: As efficient as using constants?

Comment: It should. `&typeid(PositionComponent)` should be a compiler constant (or it probably translates internally to `&__ PositionComponent__typeinfo` or sth.). Maybe take a look at the assembler code if you want to be sure.

Comment: I'm trying this (and have tried multiple variations):

`map<const type_info*, System<Component> > systems; System<PositionComponent> pc; const type_info *tid = &typeid(PositionComponent); systems[ tid ] = pc;`

but I get an error saying `No match for 'operator='`, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The error says: `System<Component>` does not have an `operator=`. Maybe you want to use `System<Component>*` (or `boost::shared_ptr` of it). Or otherwise implement the `operator=`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create some constants (ex. POSITION_COMPONENT=1) and then map those integers to instances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way to avoid creating constants like that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use constants?

Comment: Coming from Python/javascript/..., I just don't find them particularly  elegant. Not that it's a valid reason to avoid them :)

Comment: No. C++ does not have introspection. There's nothing a sane person wants to use that corresponds to retrieving the class object for an instance in Java. If you want a runtime type system, you build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure there was no way.

Comment: Syntactically, they aren't so elegant, but they can be implemented to use much less memory than the counterpart which you have suggested. Additionally, why don't you just add a static function which returns the instance? But you gain quite a bit of bulk (in memory and complexity) when you write a type system versus using numerical constants which can be used with the char type to save 3 bytes.